# Submit a form after an event. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events, form-for

Here is the part of code I am working on.

```
<td class= "block" id=<%= dom_id(Block.find(block.id)) %> colspan=2>
   <%= form_for block do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_area :content, :size => "5x4"  %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :id_case %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :canvas_id %>
     <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "save" %>
   <% end %>
</td>
```

I would like to add another form under this one, still in the "td". And I would like this one to be submitted when I drag a special element in the  (which is droppable)

I figured out that forms can have the data-remote attribut, but I didn't really get how we have to use it. Is this attribute made for execute javascript after we've submitted the form or is it a helper that submits the form after a special element ?

If this is the second case, it really fits with my idea but I really didn't understand how to use it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: few words in the question are invisible because of the tags are evaluated in the RTF

Comment: I don't get what you said...

Comment: I would like to add another form under this one, still in the .???\

Comment: Still in the "<td>"...I didn't see that thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you want to know here, but a form with `data-remote="true"` means that it will be submitted by Ajax rather than a 'normal' submit. You can add `remote: true` to your form like this:

```
<%= form_for(@post, remote: true) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

The resulting form will have a `data-remote="true"`.

To submit a form by Ajax after you have dropped your element you can do the following using jQuery:

```
$("#your-droppable-element").droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#your-form').submit();
  }
});
```

I hope that helped :)